# How can I add padding-right to an input type="number" when aligning right?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I can't believe I haven't been able to find anything about this problem.

In my new project the future user will have a column with some `input type="number"`, and as numeric fields (there is not a single `text`one) I want the numbers aligned to the right.

I found the numbers too close to the arrows so, logically, I added to them a `padding-right`.

To my surprise, It seems I can't separate a little the numbers from the arrows. `padding-right` moves the arrows along the numbers.

Basically only `Opera` do the `padding` the right way. but not the other main 3 browsers I have tested so far as you can see in the image below.

[image]

So. Is there any way to separate numbers from arrows so it works at least in `Firefox` and `Chrome` (as we recomend for our web app's these 2 browsers?)

a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/vaLa8yst/) with a simple example

Comment: Remove padding right

add css

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
         margin-left: 20px;   }

same to others browsers

Comment: depending on your use case, you might prefer to use type=tel instead of number.

Comment: Nope. I want the arrows as the user may have a close range on numbers to input and I want the arrows there. @SpiRT: that works for chrome, do you know firefox equivalent? (I don't care about ie)? and You can put it as an answer and I'll give you credit

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Rather than using `padding-right` use the following CSS

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, 
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button { margin-left: 20px; }
```

and for Firefox above solution won't work, so the best solution is just to hide it :

```
input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

or you can try to "play" with some jquery plugin.

Comment: Ty SpiRT. unfortunately I can't hide the arrows for Firefox but at least it will work for chrome (which we give preference over Opera)

Comment: @SpiRT it is hiding the up down buttons in firefox

Answer (score 11):

This is pretty annoying, in my case i solved the situation by passing the spinner to the left.

```html
<input dir="rtl" type="number"/>
```

Comment: The `<input>` tag does not use or need a closing slash.

Comment: Doesn't work, shows the cursor in the wrong location when using ltr numerals

Comment: also shows negative sign in the other side

Answer (score 6):

**Left align the field in CSS**

```css
[type="number"] {
  text-align: right;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="9999" placeholder="Enter value ...">
```

*As suggested by [@Pedro Pam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47205406)*

Comment: I tried this, but there is a problem when you have to use negative numbers. Instead of "-100" the value it is shown as "100-". (tested on Firefox and Chrome)   :(

Comment: @CJNimes yes this is a little hack that unfortunately wouldn't work if negative numbers are required.

Answer (score 2):

```js
webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {
  replaceUI: 'auto',
  types: 'number'
});
webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://afarkas.github.io/webshim/js-webshim/minified/polyfiller.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
  <input type="number" value="1000" min="0" step="0.01" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="100" class="currency" id="c1" />
</div>
```

[Webshim](https://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html) is a polyfill library that enables you to reliably use HTML5 features across browsers, even if native support is lacking.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UC6tG/212/)

Comment: This is a good answer but I woudl need to install "polyfill" and the project is already much, much bigger than we were expecting. I would love a css solution or, if not possible, a little jquery script. Anyway ty for yout answer and if no other way I will give You the right answer credit in a couple days. ty

Comment: Ya you have to use polyfill. If i get any solution with css I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Also old and I'm primarily leaving this one here for myself if this happens again. I ran into a similar problem and here's how I solved it. It presumes that you have a maximum for your number: if not, set a maximum high enough that users will never reach it.

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="999999" step="1" name="whatever-your-number-field-is" />
```

The key to solving this in my case was in the maximum value...more specifically, the number of characters/digits in the maximum value. Using the example above, we have 6 digits.

This came into play when I wrote my CSS rules. First, I used the webkit-outer-spin-button/webkit-inner-spin-button/Firefox rules above with a small twist...I used ems for my margin:

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button { margin-left: 0.5em;} 
input[type=number] {-moz-appearance:textfield;}
```

Then I defined my width using the number of digits above.

```
input[type='number'] {width: 6em; text-align: right;}
```

Now, because this is a number field, a user can "type over the boundary" and type a number such as 99999999. I used a jQuery keyup function to automatically lower the number to the max in these cases.

I'll put it together in the snippet below so you can see it.

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button { margin-left: 0.5em;} 
input[type=number] {-moz-appearance:textfield;}
input[type='number'] {width: 6em; text-align: right;}
```

```html
 <input type="number" min="1" max="999999" step="1" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I found a other "solution", after stumble over this.

a solution is with text-indent and calc:

```
[type="number"] {
    text-indent: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

I found this solution by check possible css properties for Input on:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Property_compatibility_table_for_form_controls

**Edit:**

Sorry, that only work for fix defined number length as it's still left aligned.

A heavy JS solution with that property would be possible using the approach from this code Pen (calculate real text size):
https://codepen.io/Momciloo/pen/bpyMbB