# spacing in html input type=number with text-align:right

Tags: html, input, text-align

within a html form I have an `<input type="number" style="text-align: right;">`

```css
input {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="123456">
```

It looks like this:

[image: Input]

Is there a way to define some little space between the number and the up/down controls?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add padding-right to an input type="number" when aligning right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505389/how-can-i-add-padding-right-to-an-input-type-number-when-aligning-right)

Comment: No, it does not, as I want some spacing between the number and the up/down control. padding(-right) just moves the number together with the controls.

Comment: that linked topic explains exactly that. You have do add a margin to the buttons itself

Comment: Sorry - I checked the code you added, only

Comment: In fact it describes same issue - interesting enough, that after so many years it's still same for all described browsers. Maybe someone knows an other way to do it for current browsers?